# AutoFac - How to register and resolve an object with parameter?

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-configuration

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
   private IDb db;
    public FooController (IDb context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string value)
    {
        var output = new DoSomethingElse(value);
    }
}
```

`DoSomethingElse` object is used by couple of methods in this class but it's not a requirement for all the methods. How do I register and resolve `DoSomethingElse`?

Comment: You use the Autofac factory registration

Comment: You resolve types not methods

Comment: @TimSchmelter he said `DoSomethingElse()` not the method `DoSomething`

Comment: @CallumLinington: true, but it's just another mehotd, isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ummm, no.... it's a class type. It depends how the OP wants to resolve it

Comment: @CallumLinington: why is this method a class-type? How do you know what it returns or where it is?

Comment: @sundar where does `value` come from, because if you want the container to register this type the container will need to know where the value comes from. If it is from configuration it should be really straightforward

Comment: @Callum - Sorry for the typo. DoSomethingElse is a type. The value doesn't come from configuration. It's known at runtime.

Comment: Why don't you resolve it in the constructor. And pass the `value` in during the method call....

Comment: I would like AutoFac to resolve dependencies for FooController. Is it okay to new up certain instances instead of AutoFac resolving it?

Comment: Since it is used by only couple of methods. I don't want an instance to be created everytime FooController is instantiated by AutoFac.

Comment: Then create a factory and inject that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as I understand it:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
   private IDb db;
    public FooController (IDb context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string value)
    {
        var output = new DoSomethingElse(value);
    }
}
```

You don't want to instantiate the `DoSomethingElse` type everytime you instantiate the `FooController`. You also want to provide it with a value at run time.

So this calls for the Factory Pattern:

```
public interface IDoSomethingElseFactory
{
    IDoSomethingElse Create(string value);
}

public class DoSomethingElseFactory : IDoSomethingElseFactory
{
    public IDoSomethingElse Create(string value)
    {
        // Every call to this method will create a new instance
        return new DoSomethingElse(value);
    }
}

public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private IDb db;
    private readonly IDoSomethingElseFactory doSomethingElseFactory;

    public FooController (
        IDb context,
        IDoSomethingElseFactory doSomethingElseFactory)
    {
        db = context;
        this.doSomethingElseFactory = doSomethingElseFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string value)
    {
        // this will be the point at which a brand new
        // instance of `DoSomethingElse` will be created.
        var output = doSomethingElseFactory.Create(value);
    }
}
```

Then to register this:

```
builder.RegisterType<DoSomethingElseFactory>()
       .As<IDoSomethingElseFactory>()
```

Comment: Basically creating an instance logic has been moved to the factory. That doesn't solve my problem. Is there a way for AutoFac to resolve this instance instead of explicitly creating a new one?

Comment: It makes your solution far more testable now. The logic for instantiating the class as be abstracted out of your current class removing a responsibility from your controller. So to summarise this pattern has given you a lot of benefits, SOLID adherence and testability. You shouldn't be concerned with newing up instances thinking it's a performance overhead, this is premature optimisation and won't get you very far.

Comment: I don't think newing up instances is a performance overhead. The main idea of using AutoFac is to invert the control of object creation to the framework instead of creating explicit instances by the application.

Comment: Yes, this is what my solution does! However, if you want to provide the `string value` at runtime then how is `autofac` going to know about that `string`? This is why we have a factory. Let the factory decide how to create the instance, then in your autofac configuration know how to create the factory. I can assure you this solution is what you need, and it is doing everything you want and are saying!

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for https://codefirst.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/delegate-factories-with-autofac/

Comment: This is a factory implementation though... same thing but my solution is cleaner and more powerful. More powerful because mine supports decorators, multiple implementations, testability.